# Right to left column order in index for arabic with context

Tags: context, arabic, right-to-left

I have this MWE the problem I'm facing is columns order which I need RTL but it appear LTR

I tried with `\setupregister[align=r2l]` and with `\setupregister[style=\righttoleft]` but it didn't succeed

```
\setuppapersize[A4]
\mainlanguage[ar-dz] 
\setupdirections[bidi=global,method=one]
\setupalign[r2l] 

\definefontfamily [myfont][serif][Amiri]   [features=arabic]
\setupbodyfont [myfont]

\setupregister[align=r2l]

\starttext

اللُّغَة العَرَبِيّة هي أكثر اللغات تحدثاً ونطقاً ضمن مجموعة اللغات السامية، وإحدى أكثر 
اللغات انتشاراً في العالم، يتحدثها أكثر من 467 مليون نسمة، ويتوزع متحدثوها في 
الوطن العربي،
 \index{بسم }
 بسم 
\index{نص}
 نص
 \index{أبجد} 
 أبجد
 \index{جسد} 
 جسد

\completeindex

\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup the columns for the register with:

```
\setupmixedcolumns[register][direction=reverse]
```

[image]